# Alter single array's value within list of arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

What I'm attempting to do is change the value of a single array within my list of arrays (which I use for saving products in a session) by getting it's unique product ID.

I'm using the following code:

```
function removeProductFromBasket($itemID)
{
// Loop through products
foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $arr => $prod) {

    // Check if product is already included
    if ($prod['productid'] == $itemID) {
        echo $itemID;
        $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$arr]['quantity'] = 0;
    }
}
}
```

And my array looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [productid] => 18 [quantity] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [productid] => 2 [quantity] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [productid] => 4 [quantity] => 4 ) )
```

Currently the function is being called using

```
href="'.removeProductFromBasket($productID).'"
```

Comment: Your function does not return anything.

Comment: Should the function return anything if the intention is to alter the session only?

Comment: It should return something for the `href` (at the end of your question) to get a reasonable value.

Comment: @Wessah `$_SESSION` being a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) you don't *need* to return anything to alter it, but modifying superglobals' value anywhere in the code tends to create more brittle code that is harder to maintain. Also, what @trincot said ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Seperate the concerns

The first problem I see with the current implementation, is that it "magically" acts on the `$_SESSION` variable. By doing so, you limit your ability to modify the logic in the future since the implentation of the logic is so tightly soupled with how the data is being stored. You also run the risk of forgetting that you had a function somewhere else in the code that also altered the value of `$_SESSION`, thus making the behavior of `removeProductFromBasket` unpredictable and vulnerable to bugs.

To fix this issue, you need to decouple your function from the `$_SESSION`. You can achieve this by adding a parameter to the function signature that takes in the shopping cart as an array.

```
function removeProductFromBasket($cart, $itemID)
{
    // Loop shopping cart
    foreach($cart as $key => $productArr) {

        // Check if product is already included
        if ($productArr['productid'] == $itemID) {
            echo $itemID;
            $cart[$key]['quantity'] = 0;
        }
    }

    return cart;  // return the updated cart
}
```

By modifying the code in this way allows you to handle the `$_SESSION` elsewhere, maybe in a wrapper object or something of the sort without affecting the logic of the item removal of the shopping cart. It also allows you to more easily change how the information is persisted. Say you wanted to use Redis or some other data store, you would have less lines to modify to make the change.

## Calling the function

The other problem I see with your current implementation is the way the function is called. From your sample code, I'm guessing that the full line ressembles something like this:

```
echo '<a href="'.removeProductFromBasket($productID).'">Remove this</a>
```

Since PHP is executed on the server side, what this is doing is calling the function `removeProductFromBasket` when the page gets loaded. This means that by the time the page is rendered and loaded on the client side, the item has already been removed, and the href will look like `href="12345"` du to the `echo` in your function.

Instead, you should be echoing a valid url to the item removal logic, with Item ID proerly concatenated as a parameter.

**form.php**

```
foreach($_SESSION['shoppingCart'] as $key => $item) {
    echo '<a href="http://www.example.com/path/to/file.php?itemId='.$item['productid'].'">Remove this</a>
}
```

**item_removal.php**

```
<?php
    // Make sure the session is started, $_GET is not empty and any other validation

    function removeProductFromBasket($cart, $itemID)
    {
        // Loop shopping cart
        foreach($cart as $key => $productArr) {

            // Check if product is already included
            if ($productArr['productid'] == $itemID) {
                // the echo is no longer needed
                $cart[$key]['quantity'] = 0;
            }
        }

        return cart;  // return the updated cart
    }

    $_SESSION['shoppingcart'] = removeProductFromBasket($_SESSION['shoppingcart'], $_GET['itemId']);
?>
```

---

Of course there is still room for improvement, for example by creating an object `ShoppingCart` and a wrapper `Session` around the `$_SESSION` variable, but this should be a good place for you start and build upon.